# Reading more than one value into variables using QInputDialog

Tags: qt

I have to write a small QT program that reads in 3 mark percentages separated by commas and then do some further calculations on the marks...  I have to use QInputDialog to do this but it seems like it's only possible to read in one value at a time.

at this stage I am only trying to read in and display the three marks. 
When I run this code QTCreator stops working and I have to end the process in task manager.
Any idea how I can approach this would be much appreciated.  Should I read in a string and then convert that to double values or is there a simpler way?

Thanks in advance.

Code:

```
#include <QTGui>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QString>
#include <QTextStream>


int main(int argc, char *argv[]) 
{
    QApplication app(argc, argv);
    QTextStream cin(stdin, QIODevice::ReadOnly);
    QTextStream cout(stdout, QIODevice::WriteOnly);
    double mark1, mark2, mark3;
    double passMarkNeeded = 0;
    QInputDialog::getDouble(0, "Enter marks", "Marks", 1);
    cin >> mark1 >> mark2 >> mark3;
    cout << "User entered " << mark1 << mark2 << mark3;
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: If you need to read 3 values, why don't you customize a QDialog to display 3 fields, one for each value ?

Comment: i'm doing this for a course/assignment and the instructions in the assignment says that the 3 values needs to be entered in the same input field separated by commas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously you cannot use `QInputDialog::getDouble` because it won't allow you to input 3 values separated by commas. You should use `QInputDialog::getText`, `QString::split` and `QString::toDouble`:

```
QStringList list = QInputDialog::getText(0, "Input values", "Input values:").split(",");
if (list.count() == 3) {
  double a = list[0].toDouble(),
         b = list[1].toDouble(),
         c = list[2].toDouble();
  qDebug() << "Values:" << a << b << c;

}
```

I'm not sure why you use `QInputDialog` and the standard input (cin). `QInputDialog` is for GUI apps, and `cin` is console apps. It's strange and pointless to use them together in such a way.